# C# Number Guessing Game : Get DISTINCT random number and DISTINCT input from users

Tags: c#, random

I'm building a Number Guessing Game, that reads a 4 Digit number from the Console. The computer randomly generates the 4 digit number and the user tries to guess the digits and their correct order. The program returns answer in a format 0A0B or 1A3B or 4A0B e.t.c, where it returns A if the number you guessed in correct and it's position is correct too, and will return B if the number you guessed is correct but it's position is wrong.

1. How do I insure that the numbers the computer generates are 4 distinct random numbers? Is that even possible. And would trying to control the outcome of a RANDOM number defeat the whole purpose of a RANDOM number
2. How do I make sure the user enters four DISTINCT numbers. i.e , make sure a user can't repeat a number e.g. A user shouldn't be able to enter 1031 or 9838. I've searched google and looked through C# in 21 days, but I can't  find a suitable answer.
3. A scoring function + Limiting number of chances. I understand I can implement a simple for loop that runs my program whilst the score is not zero. Once the program drops to zero, the game is terminated. Something along the lines of

   ```
   for (int score = 100; score > 0; score = score - 5) // gives a user 20 tries
   {
      //run program
      Console.WriteLine("Your score is {0}", score);
   }
   ```

   is this implemented correctly? Does anyone know a better way to do this?

The entire source code for my game is as follows.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        namespace GuessNumber
        {
            public struct answer
            {
               public int A;
               public int B;
           }
          public class Program
          {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {

          while (true)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("********************************");
            Console.WriteLine("What number do you think it is ?");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'Instrustions' or 'help' to get the game rules ?");
            Console.WriteLine("********************************");
            Console.WriteLine();

            bool GameOver = false;
            int[] targetNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();
            int hintNumber = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertIntArrayToString(targetNumber));
            while (!GameOver)
            {
                Console.Write("Answer: ");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (answer.ToLower() == "i give up" || answer.ToLower() == "exit" || answer.ToLower() == "quit")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ConvertIntArrayToString(targetNumber));
                    GameOver = true;
                    break;

                }
                if (answer.ToLower() == "hint" ) // Designed to Provide a hint.
                {
                        if (hintNumber < 2) // Check that a user has only used 2 hints
                        {
                            int Rando = GenerateRandomNumberforHint();
                            // Console.WriteLine("The Random Number generated was {0}",Rando);
                            if (Rando == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}XXX", targetNumber[Rando]); // If Rando is 0, it takes the first position of the array
                            }
                            else if (Rando == 1)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("X{0}XX", targetNumber[Rando]); // If Rando is 1, it takes the second position of the array
                            }
                            else if (Rando == 2)
                            {
                            Console.WriteLine("XX{0}X", targetNumber[Rando]);
                            }
                            else if (Rando == 3)
                            {
                            Console.WriteLine("XXX{0}", targetNumber[Rando]);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You've already used up your two hints");
                        }
                        hintNumber++;
                        continue;
               }
               if (answer.ToLower() == "instructions" || answer.ToLower() == "help")
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Instructions are as follows...");
                   continue;
               }
               if (answer.Length != 4)
               {
                   continue;
               }                      
               answer currentAnswer = CompareNumbers(targetNumber, ConvertStringToIntArray(answer));
               Console.WriteLine(currentAnswer.A + "A" + currentAnswer.B + "B");
               if (currentAnswer.A == 4)
                   GameOver = true;

               }
               Console.WriteLine("Game Over!");
               Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    protected static int GenerateRandomNumberforHint()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int Random = rnd.Next(0, 4);
        return Random;
    }
    protected static int[] GenerateRandomNumber()
    {
        int[] RandomNumber = new int[4];           
        Random seed = new Random();            
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 4)
        {
          //  RandomNumber[i] = (seed.Next() % 10).ToString()[0];
            RandomNumber[i]=seed.Next(0, 10);
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0)
            {
                if (RandomNumber[i] == RandomNumber[j])
                    i--;
                j--;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return RandomNumber;     
    }

    protected static answer CompareNumbers(int[] TargetNumber, int[] CompareNumber)
    {
        answer ReturnAnswer;
        ReturnAnswer.A = 0;
        ReturnAnswer.B = 0;            
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (TargetNumber[i] == CompareNumber[i])
                ReturnAnswer.A++;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if (TargetNumber[i] == CompareNumber[j] && i != j)
                    ReturnAnswer.B++;
            }
        }
        return ReturnAnswer;
    }

    protected static int[] ConvertStringToIntArray(string String)
    {
        int[] IntValue = new int[String.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < String.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                IntValue[i] = Convert.ToInt32(String[i].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
                //  Console.WriteLine("You must input number");
            }

        }
        return IntValue;
    }

    protected static string ConvertIntArrayToString(int[] IntArray)
    {
        char[] CharArray = new char[IntArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < CharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            CharArray[i] = Convert.ToChar(IntArray[i].ToString());
        }
        return new string(CharArray);           
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This sounds an aweful lot like "Master Mind". :-)

Answer (score 1):

1: you keep a list of generated random numbers and generate new numbers until you ahve 4 distinct ones.

2: you keep a list of entered numbers and tell the user is he enters a number he already had entered.

That is exactly the baseline stuff a book like C# in 21 days does cover if you work through it.

3: If you want to end after score is 0, yes, that is a good loop.

Answer (score -1):

For distinct random number generation

```
            int GenerateRandomNumber()
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            int randomNum = random.Next(1000, 9999);

            return randomNum;

        }

        //Make sure numbers are distinct
        int GenerateDistinctRandomNumber()
        {

            int randomNum = 0;
            var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();

            int randomNumForLoop = GenerateRandomNumber();

            int[] testArray = GetIntArray(randomNumForLoop);

            for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            {

                if (testArray.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1))
                {
                    randomNumForLoop = GenerateRandomNumber();
                    testArray = GetIntArray(randomNumForLoop);
                    i = 0;
                }

                randomNum = randomNumForLoop;

            }

            return randomNum;

        }




        //Convert int number to an array.
        int[] GetIntArray(int num)
        {
            List<int> tempList = new List<int>();

            while (num > 0)
            {
                tempList.Add(num % 10);
                num = num / 10;

            }

            tempList.Reverse();
            return tempList.ToArray();

        }
```

Key part is here, checks if have any duplicates:

```
if (testArray.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1)){...}
```